# Partition function with restrictions

Tags: integer-partitions

What is the number of ways of partitioning a positive number $k\leq mn$ using non-increasing parts such that the number of parts can be at most $n$ and the value of each part can be at most $m$?

Answer (score 4):

You are asking for the coefficients of the Gaussian or $q$-binomial coefficient. If
$$
 [n] := \frac{q^n-1}{q-1}
$$
and
$$
 [n+1]! := [n+1]\cdot [n]!, \quad [0]!=1
$$
then you want the coefficient of $q^k$ in the $q$-binomial coefficient
$$
 \frac{[m+n]!}{[m]![n]!}.
$$
There is no explicit formula. Googling on Gaussian binomial should lead to a proof.